# Spring xd app submitted to specific queue

Tags: spring-xd

after searching a while, I couldn't find how to submit a SpringXD app to Yarn using a specifiq queue.

Right now I have everything working, but when I submit the job it fails, presumably because the user doesn't have permission to submit jobs to the default queue (Any help getting the actual cause of failure will be greatly appreciated too).
I need the containers to run on higher queues, so my question is, how can I submit the Yarn application to the desired Yarn Queue?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, I still don't know how to send the job to a specific queue (tried everything on the JAVA_OPTS, but managed to submit it to the default queue and then move it to the required queue using the command yarn application -movetoqueue <appid> -queue <queue name>. Still waiting if someone can help me with the option for submitting it directly to the queue

Comment: looks like only option is to check the spring-xd code and modify the hard coding "default".